# multiple joins in fetchxml involving more than 2 entities

Tags: dynamic, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013, microsoft-dynamics

I have three entities

1. Case - new_welfarecases
2. Goal - new_casegoal
3. Activity - new_welfarecaseactivity

Now each `Case` will have multiple `Goals` and each `Goal` will have multiple `Activities`(N:1)
In the goal entity, `new_caseid` is the lookup field for `Case`

The case has a **business process flow** defined and the flow has stages like initiation, moved to next level etc

The stage of the goal is captured in field called `new_startstageofthecase`

To get list of goals for a case in particular stage I use the below **fetchxml**

```js
var fetchXml = "<fetch version='1.0' output-format='xml-platform' mapping='logical' distinct='false'>"
 +"<entity name='new_casegoal'>"
 +"<attribute name='new_startstageofthecase' />"
 +"<filter type='and'>"
 +"<condition attribute='new_startstageofthecase' operator='"+ goalFilterOption +"' value='" + currentStageId +"' />"
 +"</filter>"
+"</entity>"
+ "</fetch>";
Subgrid.control.SetParameter("fetchXml", fetchXml); //set the fetch xml to the sub grid
```

Now I want to retrieve the list of activities for a case in particular stage, how can I fetch them?

Activities entity does not have the stage field, but it has to be fetched from the goal it is associated to.

The lookup for goal in activity entity is `new_childwelfarecasegoalid`

Answer (score 3):

Everytime I need to build those queries I go to the Advanced Find in CRM.

1) Start with an advanced find to look for Activities.

2) Then add a join to Goal entity (Related Entities -> Goal),

3) Then, add a join from Goal  to the Record entity.

You can add as many filters on each of the entities. In your case a filter for the specific Stage and Record.

Then export the resulting FetchXml from the View.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand you, you want to:

- Fetch Activities that have a Goal that has an Record.
- The Record should be a specific Record.
- The Record should have a specific stage in the BPF.

A query along those lines would look like:

```xml
<fetch version='1.0' mapping='logical' distinct='false'>
  <entity name="new_Activity">
    <all-attributes /> 
    <link-entity name="new_Goal" from="new_goalid" to="new_goal">
      <link-entity name="new_Record" from="new_recordid" to="new_record">
        <filter type="and">
          <condition attribute="new_recordid" operator="eq" value="{<record-guid-here>}" />
        </filter>
        <link-entity name="processstage" from="processstageid" to="stageid">
          <filter type="and">
            <condition attribute="stagename" operator="eq" value="<stage-name-here>" />
          </filter>
        </link-entity>
      </link-entity>
    </link-entity>
  </entity>
</fetch>
```

Comment: I'd put `<all-attributes />` at root level to show something out of the query

Comment: @henrik `<link-entity name="processstage">` , should it have the name of the stage in BPF?

Comment: @vignesh: I am not quite sure what you are asking. In the example I assume you replace <stage-name-here> with your actual stage name.

Comment: @Henrik its in line no. 9
I am not sure what should be in there
is it the stage name for Record entity in business process flow?

Comment: The line "<link-entity name="processstage" from="processstageid" to="stageid">" is joining the Record entity with the Process Stage entity. This is valid if you have enabled the Record entity for Business Process Flows. It should not be necessary to change anything in that line. The actual name of the stage should go on line 11.
I hope I am not misunderstanding you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108623/discussion-between-vignesh-and-henrik).

Comment: @Henrik I am not getting the list of activities for a case in a particular stage